# part of the network path is omitted from the email body because of the space in network path

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I am trying to send an email using C# console application to our employees. In the body of the email, I need to embed a network path. I am using stringBuilder to create the body of the email. Network path is like this:

```
\\pcm-test2\shared\PCM_GEO_TEST\NGS Forms
```

I created the C# code to embed the network path like this:

```
StringBuilder TelURL = new StringBuilder().Append("<a href=" + @"\\pcm-test2\shared\PCM_GEO_TEST\NGS Forms
").Append(">HERE</a>");
```

I put the above string in the body of the email in C#. When I receive the email, I see the link that says "HERE", but when I hover over "HERE", I see, the network path like this:
\pcm-test2\shared\PCM_GEO_TEST\NGS

somehow the "Forms" part is not showing up in the body of the email. This is my complete code:

```
public void sendEmail(List<string> toList)
    {
        string from = "test@test.com";
        string UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"].ToString();
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"].ToString();
        StringBuilder TelURL = new StringBuilder().Append("<a href=" + @"\\pcm- test2\shared\PCM_GEO_TEST\NGS Forms
").Append(">HERE</a>"); 
    
        using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage())
        {
            mm.From = new MailAddress(from);

            mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("rimi@test1.com"));
          
            mm.Subject = "Test subject";
            mm.Body = TelURL.ToString();
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, password);
            client.Port = 111;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Send(mm);

        }


    }
```

How can I put the entire network path with "Forms" in the body of the email. when I try using

```
var URL = $"<a href='{System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(@"\\pcm-test2\shared\PCM_GEO_TEST\NGS Forms")}'>HERE</a>";
```

It shows like this in email body with a plus sign as you can see the image:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the TelURL string with this:

```
StringBuilder TelURL = new StringBuilder().Append("<a href=\"" + @"\\pcm-test2\shared\PCM_GEO_TEST\NGS Forms" + "\">HERE</a>");
```

entire code will be like this:

```
public void sendEmail(List<string> toList)
    {
        string from = "test@test.com";
        string UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"].ToString();
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"].ToString();
   StringBuilder TelURL = new StringBuilder().Append("<a href=\"" + @"\\pcm-test2\shared\PCM_GEO_TEST\NGS Forms" + "\">HERE</a>"); 
    
        using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage())
        {
            mm.From = new MailAddress(from);

            mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("rimi@test1.com"));
          
            mm.Subject = "Test subject";
            mm.Body = TelURL.ToString();
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, password);
            client.Port = 111;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Send(mm);

        }


    }
```

Comment: this worked right away

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this should work:

```cs
var url = $"<a href='{System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(@"\\pcm-test2\shared\PCM_GEO_TEST\NGS Forms")}'>HERE</a>";
```

That will encode the space so it will not be interpreted as two separate values. Note that your `StringBuilder` is pointless and should not be used here.

Comment: It still doesn't work, Please see the above screen shot in my original question. I have to convert url to  url.tostring in order to use it in the body of the email

Comment: @rimi, I wonder whether you need to use an actual URL, rather than a UNC path. I'll put this in a comment and, if it works, I'll add it to my answer. Instead of `@"\\pcm-test2\shared\PCM_GEO_TEST\NGS Forms"`, try `"file://pcm-test2/shared/PCM_GEO_TEST/NGS Forms"`.

Comment: How will I put "HERE". Do I need to put this in <a href

Comment: Read the actual words I wrote. Replace the part I said to replace with the part I said to replace it with. Nothing else changes.